# How can I override certain display options in Adobe Reader?

Tags: bookmarks, adobe-reader, navigation

Some PDF files can specify how they are to be displayed when first opened. I know that you can override the layout and zoom under preferences in Adobe Reader, but there are two more display options I would like to be able to override that are not found under preferences.

Some PDF files cause the navigation bar and/or the bookmarks to appear on the left side of the reader, even though I have previously hidden the navigation bar and I don't like to use the bookmarks.

Is there any way to override these two additonal display options that are sometimes set by the maker of the PDF file?

Comment: Not a direct answer but maybe try the freeware sumatra pdf (in my case I choose display 2 pages in options : default layout : "facing" and default zoom : "fit page") and it applies automatically to all pdf files.

Comment: @David: +1, was just about to recommend a better reader than that bloatware the OP uses.

Comment: I use Foxit Reader, but I'm working on modifying a Lite version of Adobe Reader that would use only the very basic display properties. I'd like to set it up so that no matter how the original poster of a PDF might want, the navigation bar and the bookmarks would not appear when the PDF is viewed. This is why I asked about Adobe, and not about the best reader for viewing PDFs. I can see why you might want to be suggesting other viewers. I would too.